# How to ping the vagrant ip and projects running on vagrant through browsers

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-8, virtualbox, vagrant

I've installed vagrant ubuntu/precise32 on windows8. I use this to run a rails project on that.

When I start my rails project (i.e) installed in the vagrant. It prompts me to ping `localhost` or `0.0.0.0` in the browsers. Being working on vagrant box, how is it possible to ping this on browser.

```
-deploy$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof) Maximum 
   connections set to 1024 Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

I am unable to use Vagrant because of this. Please do let me know how to view this project using browser.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what provider you are using. In the simplest case when you are using virtualbox or the likes, you can set up port forwarding in vagrant (see: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html). In order to forward ports you'll have to append your vagrant configuration block with the following:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

You'll have to run `vagrant reload` for port forwarding to be set up by vagrant. Also, you can always manually forward the ports on an already running VM through the virtualbox GUI (see http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/ for an example).

In the more complicated case where you are using a cloud provider such as EC2, cloudstack, etc., when vagrant tells you something like this:

```
Warning! The Cloudstack provider doesn't support any of the Vagrant
high-level network configurations (`config.vm.network`). They
will be silently ignored.
```

you can find out the IP of the machine by running `vagrant ssh-config` after vagrant has brought it up and use ssh tunnelling to forward the port like this:

```
ssh -N -L3000:localhost:3000 -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key vagrant@machineip
```